# OCaml: how to create an inductive type with Set argument of same type

Tags: recursion, types, set, ocaml

In OCaml I can define the following type:

```
type mytype = Base of int
            | Branch of (int * (collection -> collection))
and collection = mytype list
```

Assuming I define a comparison function based on the int value of each constructor, how can I transform `collection` to be a `Set` instead of a `list`?

Comment: Also relevant: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239045/error-cannot-safely-evaluate-the-definition-of-the-recursively-defined-module)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the cases where you will need to use recursive modules. In fact you can see that this is the actual example you get in the [documentation of the feature](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec220). So something along these lines should do it:

```
module rec Mytype : sig
  type t = Base ...
  val compare : t -> t -> int
end = struct
  type t = Base ...
  let compare v0 v1 = ...
end
and Collection : Set.S with type elt = Mytype.t 
               = Set.Make (Mytype)
```